# Strange assembly output when optimizing string hashing

Tags: c, string, assembly, optimization

when trying to create a compile-time hash macro, it worked but it had its problems. So I thought if the strings are known at compile time(which they are), the whole hashing should get optimized away to a constant.
This gcc C99 code with optimization level -O3 enabled:

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    char const *const string = "hello";
    int hash = 0;
    for (unsigned char i=0; i < sizeof string; ++i)
    {
        hash += string[i]; //reeaally simple hash :)
    }

    printf("%i", hash);
    return 0;
}
```

produced the following assembly code:

```
.LC0:
        .string "hello"
.LC1:
        .string "%i"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        movsx   eax, BYTE PTR .LC0[rip+6]
        movsx   edx, BYTE PTR .LC0[rip+7]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        lea     esi, [rax+532+rdx]
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

whilst the **same** code, I only changed "hello" to "hello w", produces this assembly code, which completely optimized the hashing away:

```c
.LC0:
        .string "%i"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     esi, 683
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

[Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:40,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:40,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:40,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:40,startLineNumber:6),source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0A%0Aint+main(void)%0A%7B%0A++++char+const+*const+string+%3D+%22hello+w%22%3B%0A++++int+hash+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(unsigned+char+i%3D0%3B+i+%3C+sizeof+string%3B+%2B%2Bi)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++hash+%2B%3D+string%5Bi%5D%3B+//reeaally+simple+hash+:)%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++printf(%22%25i%22,+hash)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.39567233384852,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg93,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc99',selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),header:(),k:47.60432766615146,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

What is the reason? Does this mean I can't use this way of hashing because it may be that the overhead won't get optimized out? How can I make sure there won't be any overhead, what are alternatives?

EDIT 1:
I have played around a bit and it seems if the number of chars in the string is 6, it won't get  optimized away if the number of chars is 7, it will

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty weird.  I mean... they should both be optimized because everything in here is constant.

Comment: with clang it works. The problem is that this hash macro is part of a library. This means if you don't have clang and include the library it may be that your whole program will run slower than my grandma

Comment: Try the following strings: "1234", "12345" and "123456".  You'll see that you get three different results.  The optimizer is working, it's selecting different strategies based on the length of the string.

Comment: I was sort of thinking it was some hard coded limit on unrolling the loop, but it appears to be related to `sizeof`.  If you make it a 20 character string and hard-code the loop condition to `i < 20`, it is still optimized. EDIT: or... even better, if you include `string.h` and use `strlen`, you stay optimized as well.

Comment: oh man thats not good

Comment: If you used `unsigned char`, your compiler could in theory optimize it using `psadbw` for horizontal sums of 8 or 16 byte chunks of the string.  (It's actually still a win for signed bytes, but with some preprocessing.)

Comment: As others are pointing out, `sizeof (char*)` is not what you want here.  `sizeof` will probably work as you want if you declare the array as `const char string []` instead of `const char *string`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sizeof is wrong here. It returns the size of the char pointer not the length of the string.

In your case it is an UB and the compiler cannot optimize it out as you read outside string literal bounds. it is a clang bug not the feature.

if you do it properly gcc will optimize it as well

```
int main(void)
{
    char const string[] = "hello";
    int hash = 0;
    for (unsigned char i=0; i < sizeof(string); ++i)
    {
        hash += string[i]; //reeaally simple hash :)
    }

    printf("%i", hash);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YCCNCt

Comment: I agree that this is the issue, but it is still kind of weird that it doesn't optimize it since sizeof(char*) should be constant...

Comment: how can compiler know what is past the end of the known data?